# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

frontend code:

```
{

(opp||[]).map(opps=>{
    return(
        <div className="card OppCard">
        <div className="card-body" >
            <h4>{opps.title}</h4>
            <p><b>Author : {opps.postedBy.name}</b></p>
            <p style={{ "margin": "0px" }}>Description : {opps.desc}</p>
            <p style={{ "margin": "0px" }}>Location : {opps.location}</p>
            <p style={{ "margin": "0px" }}>Experience Required : {opps.experience}</p>
            <p style={{ "margin": "0px" }}>Last Date to Apply : {opps.ld}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}) 
}
```

At `<p><b>Author : {opps.postedBy.name}</b></p>` this line error occurs
here is a pic attached for opps object:
[image: opps is the object and postedBy is also an object, how should I access opps.postedBy.name????]

Comment: you do `opps.postedBy && opps.postedBy.name` this will work

Comment: @AshishKamble its undefined

Comment: @AshishKamble thnx bro it worked, can u explain it though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whenever you try to access json object, check if it is undefined or not beffore calling method or accessing properrty
replace this line,

```
<p><b>Author : {opps.postedBy.name}</b></p>
```

with this, instead, this will work because you are checking before accessing it, also when you try to `.filter()` or `.map()` first check if it is empty or not, if not empty then only call, else it will throw error

```
<p><b>Author : {opps.postedBy && opps.postedBy.name}</b></p>
```